# Groovy way to convert empty string to null

Tags: string, groovy

I want a Groovy function which will return null if the passed in value is an empty string and return the string otherwise. This was what I could come up with..

```
def emptyStringNullConverter(a) {
    return a?.toString()?.length() == 0 ? null : a
}
```

But is there a Groovier way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just do:

```
def emptyStringNullConverter(a) {
    a ?: null
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Tim, this is why I love Groovy!

Comment: how would you modify this if you also wanted to trim the String before returning?

Comment: `a?.trim() ?: null`